# Learning over Multinomial data

Tags: classification, multinomial-distribution, train

I have a training data with 68 features... Each of which is a different multinomial distribution. Eg. Feature 1 can take 1 of 4 values while feature 2 can take one of 10 values.

Which classifier or model can I used to train over this data?

Comment: yes. I want to create a prediction model

Comment: No. Just True or False.

Comment: I tried logistic. Its not giving good results.

Comment: You should post the output of logistic regression here so that members can opine on further strategies.